# ImportError being generated when trying to run django-celery worker process

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to integrate django-celery into an existing site and I'm coming up against an error that I can't seem to get fixed.

For context, I went through the [Django first steps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) and the test project was successful, ie everything worked as it should.

Now, in my existing project, I can't get the celery worker running from the command line:

```
manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info --settings=myproject.settings.dev_settings
```

When i run that I get the following stack trace and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sites\corecrm\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\management\commands\celery.py", line 22, in run_from_argv
    ['%s %s' % (argv[0], argv[1])] + argv[2:],
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 901, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 187, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 893, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 868, in execute
    return cls(app=self.app).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 148, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 118, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 220, in run
    return self.target.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celeryd.py", line 153, in run
    return self.app.Worker(**kwargs).run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py", line 162, in run
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\loaders\base.py", line 130, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\loaders.py", line 138, in import_default_modules
    self.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\loaders.py", line 141, in autodiscover
    self.task_modules.update(mod.__name__ for mod in autodiscover() or ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\loaders.py", line 176, in autodiscover
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\loaders.py", line 195, in find_related_module
    return importlib.import_module('%s.%s' % (app, related_name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\sites\corecrm\people\tasks.py", line 15, in <module>
    from people.models import Customer, CustomerCsvFile, CustomerToTag, get_customer_from_csv_row
  File "C:\sites\corecrm\people\models.py", line 163, in <module>
    UserProfile._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0]._max_length = 75
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 351, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 380, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 469, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 483, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in get_models(only_installed=False):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 197, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\sites\corecrm\booking\models.py", line 17, in <module>
    from people.models import Customer, UserProfile
ImportError: cannot import name Customer
```

To try and work out what the booking/models.py script sees in people I added the following at the start:

```
import people
print 'path: %s' % people.__path__
for item in dir(people):
    print item
```

and that gives me the following output:

```
path: ['C:\\sites\\corecrm\\people']
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
path: ['C:\\sites\\corecrm\\people']
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
```

however, when I run `manage.py shell --settings=myproject.settings.dev_settings` I get the following output:

```
path: ['C:\\sites\\corecrm\\people']
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
path: ['C:\\sites\\corecrm\\people']
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
models
```

As you can see the `models` module is available at the end of the 2nd list for the shell command (and I've confirmed this is also the case for manage.py commands other than celery).  How would I make sure that module is available at the same point when I run the celery command?

EDIT: I've now also set up this project on an Ubuntu VM and I'm getting the same error when I try to run the worker manage command. Any ideas? Anyone?

ANOTHER EDIT: I've pasted the code for booking/models.py and people/models.py at http://pastebin.com/fTVVBtB4

Comment: Aren'you missing a "__init__.py" (double underscore before & after init) file in the people/ directory to tell Python it is a package ?

Comment: It wouldn't exist at all without the `__init__.py`

Comment: @Ricola3D: No, the `__init__.py` file is there, otherwise trying to run the shell management command (or any other command) wouldn't work. Also, the people app was created using `manage.py startapp people`, which automatically puts `__init__.py` in the directory

Comment: Circular import perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this line is your problem:

```
File "C:\sites\corecrm\people\models.py", line 163, in <module>
    UserProfile._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0]._max_length = 75
```

While you're still busy importing from `people.models`, this line (in particular `get_field_by_name`) forces Django to evaluate the model and setup all relationships between that model and it's related models. This, in turn, forces an import of `Customer` in `people.models`, while you're still busy importing that exact model. This is what results in an `ImportError`.

For a working solution you'll need to post your models.py.

Why does this error only occur with celery? I can't say for sure without some more information, but my best guess is that Celery handles importing everything slightly different (Django probably doesn't import `Customer`, `CustomerCsvFile`, `CustomerToTag` and `get_customer_from_csv_row` all at once) and that this exposes the bug in your code.

EDIT/SOLUTION:
I would remove this line:

```
UserProfile._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0]._max_length = 75
```

And move it to the instance level, into the `__init__` method:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0]._max_length = 75
        super(UserProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If the cause of the issue is indeed what I think it is, this will fix the circular import while providing the same functionality. If the max_length functionality gets broken somehow (most likely because internally a max_length validator is added to CharField and _max_length is changed too late) I would instead override the complete `username` field in the init method:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field_by_name('username')[0] = models.CharField(max_length=75, etc.)
```

Comment: I've posted a link to the code rather than add it to this question cuz it's fairly big